# Pairwise alignment using CIGAR String

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogenetics, errors

I want to perform pairwise alignment and get the resulting CIGAR string (Concise Idiosyncratic Gapped Alignment Report). A fuller description being [here](https://www.drive5.com/usearch/manual/cigar.html)

The channel can emit insertions, deletions and substitution errors.

For example, if the input was *AAGCT*

Then the output could be *AAAAGGC*

Where there were the following errors in the following positions.

1, Insertion of A at first position
2, Insertion of A at second position
3, Insertion of G at the third position
4, Deletion of T at the last position

I want to know how I could obtain the CIGAR string given two sequences. In addition, could I use viterbi algorithm for this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to obtain CIGAR string given two sequences

Comment: Hi @DukeGlacia could you check the answer? It looks pretty good, and thereafter consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [basic rules](https://jef.works/blog/2017/03/28/CIGAR-strings-for-dummies/) and preferring the `AAG` contiguous
we can write:

```
  01234
  AAGCT     (ref) 
AAAAGGC     (query)
```

So the CIGAR string is `2I3M1I1D` that is:

- `2I` insert 2`A`s  at the start:
- `3M` match the 3 bases `AAG`
- `1I` insert the `G`
- `1D` delete the final `T`